# objective c how can we handle airpod play/pause events

Tags: ios, objective-c, playback, pause, airpods

I am unable to pause video when airpod is removed from ear. I searched in google but no luck. please suggest some tutorials or apple developer documents for handling of airpod events.

Comment: As of this writing, Airpods API is not publicly available

Comment: @eshirima Do you have any idea how to handle it?

Comment: I don't know of any way to handle this. Unfortunately you're at the mercy of both Apple and the user. If the user has turned off the Automatic Ear Detection feature, there's nothing else you could do.